# Use crontab job send mail, The email text turns to an attached file which named ATT00001.bin

Tags: linux, shell, email, cron

I want to analysis some data in one linux server,then send the it as Email text to my Email account , But when i execute this shell scripts in shell command, It works well, Weird is that when i put all the procedure into crontab job, The Email text will turns to an attached file, Can someone help?

```
#* * * * * sh -x /opt/bin/exec.sh >> /opt/bin/mailerror 2>&1

/* exec.sh */
#/bin/sh
cd /opt/bin
./analysis.sh > test
mail -s "Today's Weather" example@example.com < test
```

But when i execute exec.sh in shell command line directly, The Email will get text, Can someone explain it for me, grate thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Ran into the same problem myself, only I'm piping text output into `mailx` - Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08

When running the script on the command line the email came out as normal email with a text body.
However, when I ran the exact same script via `crontab` the body of the email came as an attachment - ATT00001.BIN (Outlook), application/octet-stream (mutt) or "noname" (Gmail).

Took some research to figure this out, but here goes:

**Problem**

Mailx will, if it encounters unknown / control characters in text input, convert it into an attachment with application/octet-stream mime-type set.

From the man page:

> for any file that contains formatting characters other than newlines and horizontal tabulators

So you need to remove those control characters, which can be done with i.e. `tr`

```
echo "$Output" | /usr/bin/tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' | mail ...
```

However since I had Norwegian UTF8 characters: æøå - the list expand, and you don't really want to maintain such a list, and I *need* the norwegian characters.

And inspecting the attachment I found I had only \r, \n the "regular" ASCII characters in range 32-176 - all printable **and** 184 and 195 --> UTF8

**Sollution**

Explicitly set the locale in your script:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF8" ; export LANG
```

Run `export` in your shell - or `setenv` if you run `csh` or `tcsh` to determine what your locale is set to.

**Explanation**

Mailx - when run in your shell - with LANG set to .UTF8, will correctly identify the UTF8 chars and continue.

When run in `crontab` LANG is not set, and default to LANG=C, since by default crontab will run only a restricted set of environment variables (system dependant).

mailx (or other programs) will then *not* recognize UTF8 characters and determine that the input containes unknown control characters.

My issue was UTF8 characters, yours could be other control characters in your input. Run it through `hexdump` or `od -c`, but since it works OK in a regular shell I'm suspecting LANG issues.

**References:**

- [linux mail < file.log has Content-Type: application/octet-stream (a noname attachment in Gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343106/linux-mail-file-log-has-content-type-application-octet-stream-a-noname-attac)
- http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. (I've exported LANG="ko_KR.utf8")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting the language within my script resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had this same issue and none of the above fixed the problem. Moving the extra return in the file fixed the issue for me:

```
cat logfile | tr -d \\r | mailx -s'the logfile' to-me@.....
```

Thanks to this forum:

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/445955-mailx-creates-unwanted-attachment

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you change this in your script**

```
#/bin/sh
```

to be replaced by

```
#!/bin/sh
```

**Coming to the problem**

Your script assumes that it is being run from a particular directory (note that almost every path is a relative path, not an absolute path). cron happens to be running it from another directory.

The Fix for text appearing on email

```
mydir=$(dirname "$0") && cd "${mydir}" || exit 1
./opt/bin/analysis.sh > test 
mail -s "Today's Weather" example@example.com < /opt/bin/test
```

**Explanation**

$0 is the (possibly relative) filename of the shell script being executed. Given a filename, the dirname command returns the directory containing the filename. 
So, that line changes directories to the directory containing the script or exits with an error code if either dirname or cd fails.

**OR try to have full path like**

```
./opt/bin/analysis.sh > test 
mail -s "Today's Weather" example@example.com < /opt/bin/test
```

Note: The same problem is discussed earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668588/the-script-runs-from-command-line-but-crontab-fails)

**FOLLOW UP:**

Try to remove

`sh -x /opt/bin/exec.sh >> /opt/bin/mailerror 2>&1`

and instead use

`sh  /opt/bin/exec.sh 2>&1 >> /opt/bin/mailerror`

**FOLLOW UP**

You have to restart cron for changes to take effect if you do not use the crontab command to edit the file.

```
crontab -l > oldcrontab
cp oldcrontab newcrontab
echo "$newline" >> newcrontab
crontab < newcrontab
```

Comment: hey, man, I tried every single way, but all failed, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: please post uname output and also your complete script output

Comment: Can you give me an email, I will send you the whole files.

Comment: did you try the follow up answers?? Please post here by modifying continentals

Comment: Please post uname output and also your complete script output if you expect some help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cron was not a shell script but a PHP script (so I couldn't put the `export LANG` thing):

```
0 9 * * * apache php /test/myscript.php | mail -s "CRON - myscript" foo@bar.com
```

---

**Solution:**

In order to fix the same issue (content is mailed as attachment instead of body), I add **`LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`** at the beginning of the cron file:

```
MAILTO=vme1.etc-crond-backoffice-conf
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

0 9 * * * apache php /test/myscript.php | mail -s "CRON - myscript" foo@bar.com
```

**NB:** puting `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` in the `/etc/environment` file and restarting cron service worked too.

---

**Reference:**

- Set LANG in crontab https://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/

Answer (score 0):

None of the supplied solutions worked for me, but if you're trying to send an **empty** message body I found a workaround.

Since the message body is sent in an empty attachment, I noticed this command line option:

```
--[no-]skip-empty-attachments
                         skip attachments with empty body
```

When including this argument, I no longer am getting that problem.