# Send email with body and attachment with mailx

Tags: bash, sh, mailx

How do you send an email with both a body and attachment with mailx?

This code will send an email with a body:

`cat $body | tr -d \\r | mailx -s "SUBJECT" foo@bar.com`

*`tr -d \\r` is necessary in this case because if the body is not piped through `tr`, it will send as a .bin attachment (for this particular body). Found the solution to the body sending as .bin here: [Use crontab job send mail, The email text turns to an attached file which named ATT00001.bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999690/use-crontab-job-send-mail-the-email-text-turns-to-an-attached-file-which-named)*

I have tried putting `-f $attachment` after the subject, but am given the error, `More than one file given with -f`, and the command will not run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `mailx`'s man page :

```
-a file
          Attach the given file to the message.
```

`-f` makes mailx process a file as if it was provided on stdin, so you encountered an error because you were providing data to `mailx` both through stdin and a file.

Comment: There's the answer. I'm embarrassed. Thank you.