# E-mail script sending file ATT00001 instead of text in body of e-mail

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm attempting to write a program that will monitor the disk usage and send an e-mail if it exceeds the threshold. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,psutil,smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

THRESHOLD = 90
partitions = psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)
message = 'WARNING: DISK OVER ' + str(THRESHOLD) + '% FULL'

#for loop to iterate through disks and monitor usage
for p in partitions:
    diskuse = (psutil.disk_usage(p.mountpoint).percent)
    if psutil.disk_usage(p.mountpoint).percent >= THRESHOLD:
            msg = MIMEText(message)
            msg["From"] = "****@***.com"
            msg["To"] = "****@***.com"
            msg["Subject"] = "DISK(S) OVER THRESHOLD"
            P = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
            P.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

When I try to run the program as it is here, the email will be sent but rather than sending a text email, i receive a file named ATT00001. I have tried running the program without `diskuse` and it worked the way I expected but I cannot figure out why it won't allow me to send both `message` and `diskuse`

Comment: How did you sent `diskuse`? I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the email you're trying to send contains special characters. When it contains special characters (such as `\r`) then it will change it to an attachment.

[This stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999690/use-crontab-job-send-mail-the-email-text-turns-to-an-attached-file-which-named) talks quite a bit about that.

They claim that `LANG="en_US.UTF8" ; export LANG` will solve your problem.